# Audio always stops halfway through the scene (phaserjs 3.70)

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I’m working on a game and I started analyzing the game’s audio in Phaser 3. The audio works well at the beginning of the scene, no lag or anything like that, with some tweens running along. However, at a certain point (usually halfway through the scene) the audio for the entire game stops and no more sounds play.

My game config:

```
{
      autoFocus: true,
      banner: false,
      disableContextMenu: true,
      roundPixels: true,
      audio: {
        disableWebAudio: false,
      },
      physics: {
        default: "arcade",
        arcade: {
          debug: false,
        },
      },
      render: {
        antialias: true,
        preserveDrawingBuffer: false,
        failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat: false,
        powerPreference: "high-performance",
      },
      type: Phaser.AUTO,
      fps: {
        target: 15,
      },
      plugins: {
        scene: [
          {
            key: "SpinePlugin",
            plugin: window.SpinePlugin,
            start: true,
            mapping: "spine",
          },
        ],
      },
      scale: {
        mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
        autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
        expandParent: true,
      },
      scene: BootScene
    };
```

I think it’s important to say that the user only sees the execution of the tweens in this scene, they don’t take any action.

Comment: Is everthing running in one Scene, or do you have multiple Scene? How long/big is the Audio file? **Or simply put:** Do you have a small reproducable example, that showcases this issue?